# Horizon chart not visible when using d3.scale.log()

Tags: javascript, charts, scale, d3.js

I've successfully drawn horizon charts using the default linear scale, and they look great. Unfortunately, when I try to use the d3.scale.log() scaler, the chart never shows up; no error, just nothing. I had thought that the problem was with zeros in the input data, but even when my metrics return a single non-zero value, this occurs. Here's an example:

```
context = cubism.context(), horizon = context.horizon();
horizon.scale(d3.scale.log());
var flatMetric = context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
  var values = [];

  // convert start & stop to milliseconds
  start = +start;
  stop = +stop;

  while (start < stop) {
    start += step;
    values.push(10);
  }

  callback(null, values);
});
d3.select("body").selectAll(".horizon")
  .data([flatMetric]).enter().append("div")
  .attr("class", "horizon")
  .call(horizon);
```

If I simply replace the log scale with the linear scale, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area charts (of which a horizon chart is a special case) don't make sense on a log scale: zero is at infinity. In practice, this manifests itself as a rendering error because the coordinates are ±Infinity or NaN.

If you want to use a log scale, you'll need a different chart type without a zero baseline, such as a line chart. A comparison chart might also work. If you want to keep the horizon charts and you don't want to use a linear scale, try a sqrt (or more generally, pow) scale.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I understand that log(0) is -Infinity, but it still seems like a logarithmic scale is quite useful for showing data that has a large range. I suppose what I actually want is log(x+1), so that scale(0) returns 0. I tried to do this by setting the domain, but apparently that gets applied after the scale is done. Do you think simply modifying the scale function on my system would make sense?

Comment: So I created a new function d3.scale.logPlus1(), which is exactly the same as d3.scale.log(), except that the scale function returns linear(log(x+1)) instead of linear(log(x)). What I see is that the linear function is always returning NaN, even when the log function is returning what I expect.

Or is this just a bad idea and I need to use sqrt (which works, but people are more accustomed to a log scale over a sqrt scale)?

Comment: The problem is that the area under the curve when using a logarithmic scale is not meaningful. If you want a log scale, you should use a line chart instead of a horizon chart.

Comment: I agree with Mike that simply switching to a logarithmic scale is not meaningful here. But it makes perfect sense to split the chart into bands logarithmically while still using a linear scale within each of the bands. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ilyabo/9ck5q/4/